# R Table Return x for max(y)

Tags: r

I have two column data

```
Year    Total

1945    88
1946    109
1947    55
```

I would like R to return the Year value for maximum value of Total.  For the above data, R should return 1946.

How do I d this?

Thanks,

jcel

Comment: I suggest you do a bit of searching before your next posting.

Comment: You are looking for `with(df, Year[which.max(Total)])`

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
df<-data.frame(year=c(1945,1946,1947),total=c(88,109,55))
```

then:

```
maxYear<-subset(df,df$total==max(df$total),select=year)
```